# odbc num_rows codeigniter result_set is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc

I use this code to verify the user.

```
public function verify_user($username, $password)
{
    $q = $this->db->where('username', $username)
        ->where('password', md5($password))
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('users');

    if ($q->num_rows() === 1) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($q->row());
        echo '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo 'EMPTY';
    }
}
```

But, when it equals 1, it display nothing.

```
Array
(
)
```

It appear when I use this code to fix odbc num_rows = -1 issue: [CODEIGNITER Issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_result.php) on line 40 until 67

**EDIT =============================**

What I want to achive is this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id_user] => 2
    [username] => 114080077
    [password] => 0d5ccab9e7f4ae3fe040f143046e386c
)
```

Code that I modify is:
**Before (STABLE VERSION)**:

```
/**
 * Number of rows in the result set
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function num_rows()
{
    return @odbc_num_rows($this->result_id);
}
```

**After (ISSUE FIX)**:

```
/**
 * Number of rows in the result set
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function num_rows()
{
    if (is_int($this->num_rows))
    {
        return $this->num_rows;
    }
    elseif (($this->num_rows = @odbc_num_rows($this->result_id)) !== -1)
    {
        return $this->num_rows;
    }

    // Work-around for ODBC subdrivers that don't support num_rows()
    if (count($this->result_array) > 0)
    {
        return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_array);
    }
    elseif (count($this->result_object) > 0)
    {
        return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_object);
    }

    return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_array());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use the development version of `CI_DB_odbc_result` and keep the rest of the stuff from the 2.1 version tree. If you don't want to replace all of them, what you need to get from the repository are the following files:

```
system/database/DB_driver.php
system/database/DB_result.php
system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php
system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_result.php
```

(assuming that you only use ODBC)

There still *could* be an issue with the ODBC result class and I'll look into that, but considering that your question refers to a yet unreleased version of CodeIgniter - it would be better that you post any problem reports to either the CodeIgniter forums or the GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks for the information, sorry for the inconvenience @Narf, next time I'll post my problem to CI forums.

Comment: You're welcome. There's no inconvenience, but had I not been on stackoverflow when you posted your question, you wouldn't have gotten the answer. :)

Comment: Hi @Narf, can I ask for your recommendation about which database is nearly perfect if I use it w/ CodeIgniter, MySQL or PostgreSQL? Ms.Access database (ODBC) seems make me frustation.

Comment: Both are well supported with MySQL being one step closer to perfection. Improvements to all of the drivers are coming with CI 3.0 though. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the if condition, use:

```
$q->num_rows()
```

and try to use

`$q->result()` instead `->row()`

Comment: still displaying an empty array. When I use the Stable version of CodeIgniter 2.1, it display the result, but the num_rows is equal -1 even there is no data. So I use this code [link](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_result.php) on line 40 until 67. It works perfectly, but it make the array result empty.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but...did you load the database?

Comment: Yes, of course I autoload the database. As I said before, it display the result before I modify the code. I have edited my question, adding some information.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply @ChristianGiupponi, i've found the solution after looking the git :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by replacing the system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_result.php with this one:
[Fix Issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/9c68c3173c84041b1ee77929e540a4a4382edeee/system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_result.php)